# How to get php file name

Tags: php

I owned a website. I want to know the php file name to edit some text. There are so many files and it hard for me to get the file that i need to edit it. So, is it possible to find the php file name from the inspect element by using chromium?
Thank you.

Comment: The answer to your real question is: There is no easy way to find out which php file generated the html which you look at in the browser.

Comment: Your question is vague and unclear, what do you mean? Can you specify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **server side** web development and there is **client side** web development. Any client side code can be seen by the user who views your webpage, such as generated HTML, JavaScript, and CSS. The server side part of your website, or all PHP code, the user cannot see, for security reasons. All server side code is run on your server and it generates the client side code, which is then sent to the user's browser. The client side code is all parsed in the client's browser, which therefore is viewable by the user using "View Source" or "Inspect Element".

You are asking to view server side information from the client, which is restricted for security, so you cannot access it. Though this isn't exactly what your trying to achieve, you can access the current PHP script's file path & name and directory like this in PHP using a magic constant:

```
//outputs current script path & name
echo __FILE__;

//outputs current script dir
echo __DIR__;
```

Hope this helped in some way. Wish you the best.